# Is it possible to rotate whole echarts Instance in Apache ECharts?

Tags: rotation, echarts

I'm new to echarts so please forgive me if this is stupid newbie request. I'm trying to rotate whole chart just like in this example of [Vega Edge Bundling Example](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/edge-bundling/). On the right corner there is a tool and one option is also "rotate".
[Example Image of Vega](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzLCJ.png)
I would like to do the same thing (rotate whole graph) in echarts but I can't find a way to do it. If it is possible to do it please let me know how I can do it. Thank you for any reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not perfect but I tried.
I use function to change startAngle,I don't know why the rotation is delayed.

```js
   var option = {
  title: {
    text: 'Referer of a Website',
    subtext: 'Fake Data',
    left: 'center'
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'item'
  },
  legend: {
    orient: 'vertical',
    left: 'left'
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Access From',
      type: 'pie',
      radius: '50%',
      startAngle: 15,
      data: [
        { value: 1048, name: 'Search Engine' },
        { value: 735, name: 'Direct' },
        { value: 580, name: 'Email' },
        { value: 484, name: 'Union Ads' },
        { value: 300, name: 'Video Ads' }
      ],
      emphasis: {
        itemStyle: {
          shadowBlur: 10,
          shadowOffsetX: 0,
          shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};

var myChart2 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main2'));
myChart2.setOption(option);

function rotate() {
    var Angle=document.getElementById("range").value;
    myChart2.setOption({
    series: [{
    startAngle:Angle,
    }]
   }); 
};
```

```html
    <html lang="Zh-TW">
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.2.2/echarts.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">rotate</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6"><input type="range" class="form-control" min="0" max="360" value="10" oninput="rotate('range')" id="range"></div>
    <div id="main2" style="width:100%;height:600px;"></div
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't care about delay, it looks even cooler :) Thank you so much for example!